# Create a Wall like Instagram or FB

Tags: android, android-listview, instagram, facebook-wall

I just want to create a wall in my app just like in Instagram and Facebook.And i have no such idea to do this. I am in a search for basic idea how to create a simple wall in my Android app.Can any one plz provide a tutorial or any concept of doing this(wall)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to display some lines of content, so you have to make a custom adapter:

Start with http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429

or http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

You have to make a complex layout with all you need (author, text, image, date etc...) and work hard...