# how to create a feed like instagram

Tags: android

I have been working in android for a while and I am using `ListView` to display images from `php` server using `NetworkImageView`. Is it possible to create a `ListView` listing  images and videos like in Instagram?

Comment: Take a look at this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618438/create-a-wall-like-instagram-or-fb

Answer (score 0):

You want to display some lines of content, so you have to make a custom adapter:

Start with http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429

or http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

You have to make a complex layout with all you need (author, text, image, date etc...) and work hard..

source : [Create a Wall like Instagram or FB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618438/create-a-wall-like-instagram-or-fb)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to read the `RecyclerView` [documents](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) and create a `RecyclerViewAdapter`. You can also use `CardView` to display feeds like in cards. Here is [sample](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html).

As like you're getting feeds from `PHP` categorize them as Video and Images. And accordingly in `RecyclerViewAdapter` you can display images or stream videos.

It's also possible with `ListView` with `CustomAdapter` which contains `VideoView` and `ImageView`